# Install specific Wordpress installation with theme on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 DigitalOcean

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

Our company's partners sent us custom  Wordpress installation for website.

Installation contains  2 files:

1. installer.php
2. installation.zip (example)

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04)  guide to install `Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 14.04`.  Worked perfectly.

Then followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide to install Wordpress, but instead of downloading install from Wordpress website I used my custom installation.

Now those both files remain in `/var/www/html`

Then I accessed: `http://my_server_ip/installer.php`

And got this Error:

[image]

What I tried is:

1. Restarted Apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`
2. Set both file permisions to 777, now I got `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root edgars
   424438 Jan 20 07:52 installer.php`
3. Changed file owner to edgars now it looks like this:

   ```
      -rwxrwxrwx 1 edgars 30208410 Jan 20 07:58 201412166115237_archive.zip
       -rwxrwxrwx 1 edgars   424438 Jan 20 07:52 installer.php
   ```

Restarted again Apache, but still can't pass that test..

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you only changing the permission on the `installer.php` file? I think you should make your entire webroot writeable using something like `sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www/html`

Comment: Here is a good answer on how to set things up: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162866/correct-permissions-for-var-www-and-wordpress

Comment: @Cyclone I tried that answer, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tells you that PHP can't write into /var/www/html, so you have to change permissions in that directory. It looks like you're only changing the file permissions and not the directory.

Also, don't use 777, 755 should be enough. Or better yet, just set the directory ownership to whatever apache's username is (usually www-data).

Commands:

```
# change permissions of directory
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html 
# change ownership of directory
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

www-data may or may not be the user  apache's using for its processes; you can check for the actual username using:

```
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

Comment: I tried this command `sudo chmod -R 755 html` after that I restarted no change.

Comment: are you writing complete path to html or not? If you are not in the directory www

Comment: I am inside '/var/www/'  then I executed this command : 'sudo chmod -R 755 /html'

Comment: Updated my answer (you should remove the first /, since it tells the command that the directory html is inside the root directory of the filesystem)

Comment: @devJunk Worked perfectly :)

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds great!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
sudo chown root:www-data -R /var/www/html
```

It gives permissions to group root & user www-data.

Hope it helps.